# How to Write/read S3 bucket file From RDS Mysql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Stored Procedure to write on S3 bucket

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE export_product
()
BEGIN
 SET @SQLString = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM product INTO OUTFILE "https:\\s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\bucket\download\product.csv" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
        LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" ');
 PREPARE test2 FROM @SQLString;
 EXECUTE test2;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot write from MySQL RDS directly to S3.. Few Options:

1. you need to move to MySQL Aurora RDS( Aurora being AWS service can talk to other AWS Services ).
2. write a shell script which will run this SQL Query against your MySQL RDS. Redirect output to a flat csv file.. and then copy this csv to S3 using AWS CLI.
3. You can also evaluate AWS Data pipeline

Comment: Hi, thank you. Is any option secure file priv location in mysql to ec2 instance?

Comment: i do not understand what u mean !

Comment: [`secure_file_priv`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) is not relevant to RDS for MySQL, because `LOAD DATA INFILE` and `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` are not available.  You have no access to the filesystem in RDS, and remote disks/filesystems/volumes are not accessible.